# Qt - Grabbing pixmap from a Widget doesn't take proper alpha channel

Tags: c++, qt, transparency, alpha, qpixmap

I'm currently using the QWidget::grab() function to acquire a QFrame's pixmap (and all of its children), but the function doesn't seem to take into account if the widget doesn't have any background.

You see, my QFrame is set to "setAutoFillBackground(false)", but when its pixmap is grabbed, it seems to paint the default light-pinkish background instead of full transparency.

Replacing the pixmap with a picture containing an alpha channel works fine.
The situation I'm using this in is with QGL, so the pixmap is getting rendered later on as a texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the frame's palette's background to contain 0 alpha. This fixed the program.

Although I still believe that the grab function should take into account the bool that was set for filling the background or not - since not autofilling the background equates to the same net visual effect normally, just not when grabbed.